# QTreeView clear selection if selected item is filtered

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView that displays items and a QSortFilterProxyModel for filtering. The QTreeView is configured for SingleSelection and SelectRows.

If a selected item is removed using the filter, the next non-filtered item is selected. I want to change this behaviour. My current idea is to connect to rowsAboutToBeRemoved() and clear the selection if the selected item is removed.

```
connect(_ui.treeView->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsAboutToBeRemoved, 
[this] (const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end) {//check and clear selection});
```

However, QT changes the selection to the next item before the rowsAboutToBeRemoved() signal is triggered. So I cannot test if the removed item is the selected item.

Is there a better way to clear the selection if the item gets filtered? I would prefer a solution that does not involve deriving from QTreeView.

Answer (score 1):

rowsAboutToBeRemoved is not a signal, it is a virtual method.

See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html

It is not QTreeView, but the ItemModel that has signals for it:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged

The QTreeWidget has the signal on it's own:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged

But for a QTreeView one has to use the ItemModel and/or ItemDelegate.